# How to make a nullable field in a struct

Tags: go, nullable

I'm struggling to do table driven test, and I want do this:

```
testCases := []struct {
    name          string
    testUserID    uint
    expected      User // <- maybe nil
    expectedError error
}
```

Because the return values of tested function is `*User, error`.

User is like this, it is defined as DB scheme.

```
type User struct {
  ID uint
  CreatedAt time.Time
  UpdatedAt time.Time
  ...
}
```

But in this case, I cannot make `expected` nil.

How can I do this?

Or my approach to do table driven test is wrong?

Comment: Is `SomeType` a struct or interface. Please post more code information.

Comment: Sorry, it is struct.

Comment: Sorry SomeType is User, and it is struct. I edited my question

Comment: Then if it's a structure - make it a pointer.

Comment: @Taichi why do you think you cannot make `expected` a pointer?

Answer (score 28):

For empty field you can check for empty values which is zero value which is not nil in case of struct.

> When storage is allocated for a variable, either through a declaration
>   or a call of new, or when a new value is created, either through a
>   composite literal or a call of make, and no explicit initialization is
>   provided, the variable or value is given a default value. Each element
>   of such a variable or value is set to the zero value for its type:
>   false for booleans, 0 for numeric types, "" for strings, and nil for
>   pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps.

In your case are using the Struct not a pointer to struct. The value is not nil it is empty though

```
var user User
fmt.Println(user == User{}) // will print true
```

But since in your case the returned value is pointer to struct `*User, error` you can check for nil

```
var user *User
fmt.Println(user == nil) // will print true
```

Create struct field that is a pointer.

```
testCases := []struct {
    name          string
    testUserID    uint
    expected      *User // <- maybe nil
    expectedError error
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Go basic types have defined zero values and cannot be nil.

If you want a value to be simply nillable, make it a pointer.

If you do not want a pointer behaviour, you can use null types from third party packages,

e.g. https://github.com/guregu/null

for example int is implemented as:

```
type Int struct {
    Int   int
    Valid bool
}
```

another solution is to write your own struct with nullable value

Comment: Is there any standard for this, or at least official go draft, or issue opened? It's quite missing feature, there are many cases, where there's need to differentiate between missing value and zero value. E.g. `examResults.Score == 0` (no points), and `examResults.Score == nil` (unknown score).

Comment: You can use the null types included in the standard library in the sql package like sql.NullBool and sql.NullInt32. https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql

Answer (score 12):

You can also use special sql type:

```
type structName struct {
    id sql.NullInt64
    name sql.NullString
    field sql.NullBool
}
```

Answer (score 3):

also you can use any, and will accept any value.

```
testCases := []struct {
    name          string
    testUserID    uint
    expected      any
    expectedError error
}
```