# How to deserialize JSON when a member's type changes

Tags: json, go, deserialization

I'm writing a go program to download my newspaper and convert it into ePub.

I get the articles as JSON and figured out the structure as below (excertpt)

```
type Article struct {
    Id         string    `json:"id"`
    Type       string    `json:"type"`
    Title      string    `json:"title"`
    Author     string    `json:"author"`
    Underline  string    `json:"underline"`
    Next       Link      `json:"next"`
    Prev       Link      `json:"prev"`
}
type Link struct {
    Id    string `json:"id"`
    Paper Paper  `json:"paper"`
}
type Paper struct {
    Paper string `json:"paper"`
    Date  string `json:"date"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
}
```

An example json:

```
{
    "id": "89052007",
    "type": "article",
    "title": "The Title",
    "author": "The Author",
    "next": {
        "id": "89094743",
        "paper": {
            "paper": "xxx",
            "date": 20200822,
            "title": "Newspaper"
        },
        "title": "Next Title"
    },
    "prev": {
        "id": "89094746",
        "paper": {
            "paper": "xxx",
            "date": 20200822,
            "title": "Newspaper"
        },
        "title": "Prev Title"
    }
}
```

The issue I have is with the Next/Prev link, when there is no previous or next article. In that case, Next/Prev will not be of type "Link" but of type "bool". The JSON will simply read:

```
…
    "prev": false
}
```

As a beginner of go I need some advice how to handle this situation properly.

Currently when I "hit" such an article, my program panics:

```
panic: assignment to entry in nil map
```

I read about [How to make a nullable field in a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998165/how-to-make-a-nullable-field-in-a-struct) as suggested but cannot see how this is going to help. I simply cannot relate it to my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a nullable field in a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51998165/how-to-make-a-nullable-field-in-a-struct)

Comment: No. Not really. That's about "nil" and databases.

Comment: you could just have two structs. One with the prev field as boolean and one like you posted. When parsing fails with your posted struct just try the one with the boolean field. you could also use custom marshaling (https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2016/advanced-encoding-decoding/) where you could handle the field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface.

For example:

```
type Article struct {
    Id        string `json:"id"`
    Type      string `json:"type"`
    Title     string `json:"title"`
    Author    string `json:"author"`
    Underline string `json:"underline"`
    Next      Link   `json:"next"`
    Prev      Link   `json:"prev"`
}

type Link struct {
    Id    string `json:"id"`
    Paper Paper  `json:"paper"`
}

func (l *Link) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if string(data) == "false" {
        return nil
    }

    type link Link
    return json.Unmarshal(data, (*link)(l))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/fQhDWwO45Nt

Or:

```
type Article struct {
    Id        string       `json:"id"`
    Type      string       `json:"type"`
    Title     string       `json:"title"`
    Author    string       `json:"author"`
    Underline string       `json:"underline"`
    Next      OptionalLink `json:"next"`
    Prev      OptionalLink `json:"prev"`
}

type Link struct {
    Id    string `json:"id"`
    Paper Paper  `json:"paper"`
}

type OptionalLink struct {
    Link *Link
}

func (ol *OptionalLink) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if string(data) == "false" {
        return nil
    }

    ol.Link = new(Link)
    return json.Unmarshal(data, ol.Link)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/PMrbMJAOgaA

Comment: This looked promising but I think I made a mistake? UnmarshalJSON seems to be not invoked when I do my `json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(target)` But thanks a lot for the hint. Will see what I can do with Unmarshal

Comment: @Skeeve https://play.golang.org/p/rw-mYU8LM3R and https://play.golang.org/p/8KE8Pp9aWGg

Comment: @Skeeve if it doesn't work for you, you're doing something else wrong. Decoder.Decode and Unmarshal work the same as far as unmarshaling is concerned.

Comment: I tried that and it works. Unfortunately not in my real program :( I also can see that unmarshalJson is invoked for my correct next-Value. I've simply inserted some Println. But for my "prev":false I see no invocation of unarshalJson :(

Comment: @Skeeve I can't help you without seeing the actual code and actual input. If the code doesn't work for your "real program" that means that the code in your question is inaccurate, i.e. not representative of the "real program".

Comment: Yes, I fear so. But as you cannot access the real data without a subscription, I cannot post the real code. I'm currently debugging and trying to find out what I'm doing wrong. Your hint helped a lot.

Comment: My issue IS somewhere else. Stupid me… Not sure exactly where it is, but completely outside unmarshal. Thanks a lot again @mkopriva